# Authentication Service on GCP with data storage options in Europe

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-platform

I am looking for "authentication as a service" (fully managed, Google or any other 3rd party) that provides authentication for a web-service on Google Cloud Platform with (user) data stored on servers located in the European Union.

Currently, we use Firebase Authentication with Google as Identity Provider for authentication. After the cancelation of the US-privacy-shield last summer, we formally have to search for something else, as Firebase Authentication is currently an US service only (https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy).

Please only technical advise, as we have discussed the lets-wait-and-see option in depth already.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that you are looking for technical advise only for another Europe based authentication service, but it maybe worth mentioning that The Privacy Shield frameworks provided a mechanism to comply with data protection requirements when transferring EEA, Swiss, or UK personal data to the United States and onwards. In light of the recent European Court of Justice ruling on data transfers, Firebase has made updates to their terms to add the relevant Standard Contractual Clauses as adopted by the European Commission, which, as per the ruling, can continue to be a valid legal mechanism to transfer data under the GDPR.